# Date Picker with Simple Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with multiple date fields, Can anyone suggest me simple date picker in jquery or in simple javascript?

Answer (score 16):

Here's a really simple (no JS frameworks required) one I made, i hope you find it useful. It looks like this:
[image]

And here's the links:

- http://splinter.com.au/javascript-date-picker-that-doesnt-sucktm
- http://github.com/chrishulbert/datepicker

Comment: I can't help you there sid...I like this date picker though ... only change I had to make was to change z-index to bring the calendar to the front

Comment: @ITECH If you send a pull request i'll certainly integrate that fix :)

Comment: Looks like the data string is hardcoded here: function getDateString(dt) {
  return dt.getDate() + '-' + 
    ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'][dt.getMonth()] + 
    '-' + dt.getFullYear();
} .... so it needs to be added as a setting, or you need to edit datepicker.js manually.

Answer (score 6):

You can check with the EJ2 DatePicker from Syncfusion. The Syncfusion Essential JS 2 DatePicker is a modern JavaScript UI Controls library that has been built from the ground up to be lightweight, responsive, modular and touch friendly. Here is the code sample to render the EJ2 DatePicker.

**[datepicker.html]**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <input id="datepicker" type="text">

    <script>
        var datepicker = new ej.calendars.DatePicker({ width: "255px" });
        datepicker.appendTo('#datepicker');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Live Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/zfby6h-uep3wc?file=index.html

To explore more about EJ2 DatePicker and its functionalities, check out the following links,

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/datepicker/es5-getting-started 
Feature Tour: https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/datepicker 
Demo Samples: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/material/datepicker/default.html

For any assistance, You can ask through [Syncfusion forums](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums).

Comment: loading a base64 image and delaying loading of the page by 1-2sd is not what I call lightweight...

Answer (score 2):

I used [Keith Wood's datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) which is now merged to JQuery UI, and now became JQuery UI Date Picker. Its simple to edit it and I even made some changes to it to make it do what I desired for my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use Jquery UI datepicker. Easy and Colorful. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker

Answer (score -1):

I've used [this](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/convenient-javascript-calendar-date-picker/) and found it good.